# How to set width 100% but not bigger than value

Tags: css, width

Which is the proper way to set width to an element, setting width to let's say 960px and max-width to 100%  or the other way arround width 100% and max-width to 960px?

```
div { width: 960px; max-widht: 100% }
div { width: 100%; max-width: 960px }
```

Answer (score 5):

set width 100% but not bigger than value,

```
div{ max-width: 960px; width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap for responsive pages. It will help you to have best width for mobile and tablet. Also use media quires for best. Always go for a max width for a div or container.